# Want hide all row select option but not multiple row select options from MUIDatatables.Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I want to hide the checkbox from header row. From which all the rows can be selected. I just want to select multiple option by clicking each. So I want to hide all row select option.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [`selectableRowsHeader`](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables#:%7E:text=selectableRowsHeader) option is what you are looking for.

```html
<MUIDataTable
  title={"Title"}
  data={data}
  columns={columns}
  options={{
    selectableRowsHeader: false
  }}
/>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/muidatatables-hide-select-all-l8o1z?file=/index.js

Comment: yes!!! It worked

Comment: Great! Coding is fun ;)